# Mail::Sendmail with attachments and embed Perl in Bash script

Tags: bash, sendmail, perl

1> I want to embed below Perl script in BASH script, and the **Message** should read from a message.txt file. How to realize this?

```
  use Mail::Sendmail;

  %mail = ( To      => 'you@there.com',
            From    => 'me@here.com',
            Message => "This is a very short message"
           );

  sendmail(%mail) or die $Mail::Sendmail::error;

  print "OK. Log says:\n", $Mail::Sendmail::log;
```

2> How to attach log files via Perl script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to do it in a bash script, then maybe you can do without Perl. In your bash script have something like:

```
mutt -F $HOME/.muttrc.me -x -a attachment.file -- you@there.com < message.txt
```

This needs [mutt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mutt) and you can have a custom *.muttrc* file ($HOME/.muttrc.me in this case) to control the `From:` header:

```
my_hdr From: "Me Here" <me@here.com>
my_hdr Reply-To: me@here.com
```

Comment: Great! This answers my another question: how to change sender address on the fly using Mutt. But I am now facing another problem: `mutt -s "subject here" my@company.net < /dev/null` `Error sending message, child exited 67 (User unknown.).` This command worked well before I edited (but not modified) /etc/mail/local-host-names file.

Comment: Try `mutt -x -s "subject here" my@company.net < /dev/null`. Could it be that company.net is listed in local-host-names but the user does not exist on the system?

Answer (score 1):

The way @adamo told works fine, here's another, perhaps more performant one if there are lots of recipients:

```
cat message.txt | mail -a 'From: me@here.com' -a 'To: you@there.com' -s 'Subject for the message' you@there.com
```

Comment: I tried this command and get error message `mail: invalid option --a`.